# cloud stream v4 (reactive) - unable to use simple transform function using springboot 3

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-cloud-stream, spring-boot-3

I am new to spring cloud stream. I am not able to use the transform function (consume message, transform, produce message). Consumer function works well.

```
    @Bean
    public Function<String, String> processorBinding() {
        return s -> s + " :: " + System.currentTimeMillis();
    }
```

Binding config in application.yml

```
spring:
  cloud:
    function:
      definition: processorBinding
    stream:
      bindings:
        processorBinding-in-0:
          destination: processor-topic
        processorBinding-out-0:
          destination: consumer-topic
      kafka:
        binder:
          replicationFactor: 1
          brokers:
            - localhost:9092
```

Getting error when sending a simple string message to processor-topic via GUI kafka tool.

Output error
[check the logs here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q58Ic.jpg)

```
2023-11-17T13:47:22.584+01:00 ERROR 21151 --- [container-0-C-1] o.s.integration.handler.LoggingHandler   : org.springframework.messaging.MessageHandlingException: error occurred in message handler [org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.kafka.KafkaMessageChannelBinder$ProducerConfigurationMessageHandler@2574a232], failedMessage=GenericMessage [payload=byte[25], headers={deliveryAttempt=3, kafka_timestampType=CREATE_TIME, kafka_receivedMessageKey=[B@778d6951, kafka_receivedTopic=processor-topic, target-protocol=kafka, kafka_offset=0, kafka_consumer=org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer@5b098190, source-type=kafka, id=441f0410-7efb-1780-f210-d2e1be910c10, kafka_receivedPartitionId=0, kafka_receivedTimestamp=1700225238940, contentType=application/json, kafka_groupId=anonymous.8d99852a-9b33-43d1-b269-da2f03a7ae4c, timestamp=1700225242574}]
at org.springframework.integration.support.utils.IntegrationUtils.wrapInHandlingExceptionIfNecessary(IntegrationUtils.java:191)
at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.doHandleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:108)
at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:73)
at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.kafka.KafkaMessageChannelBinder$ProducerConfigurationMessageHandler.handleMessage(KafkaMessageChannelBinder.java:1594)
at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.AbstractMessageChannelBinder$SendingHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractMessageChannelBinder.java:1185)
```

I actually want to consume message from a topic in apache kafka, do some data massaging & checks (including IO ops), and send processed data to another kafka topic. Ensuring that the messaging platform can change in the future, thus used cloud stream. Let me know how this is possible using springboot 3.x and the best possible dependency in the ecosystem.

Expectation is the message is consumed from (processor-topic) and sent to another topic (consumer-topic) based on bindings in config.

Comment: The stack trace you provided is not complete and shows nothing relevant. The above function is very trivial and we have many tests validating such scenario so something you are not showing us. Please consider creating a small app that reproduces the issue and pushing it to Github so we can take a look.

Comment: https://github.com/brucereed1807/spring-kafka

created this repo from spring initializer using
java, maven, springboot 3.1.5 and its relevant dependencies

Comment: Also do we have a slack/ discord channel for spring related discussions ?

Comment: We used to, but community rarely participated, rather used it as a free support channel, so we closed it as we have very limited resources

Comment: Hi Oleg,

     Its a non issue. The broker version was old in my case. I was looking at easier ways to setup kafka locally and had come across a docker image spotify/kafka....Didnt check it was 7 years old. Works well with latest kafka version.